# QT bindings for Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, api, qt, qt4, delphi-2010

Why isn't anyone developing QT bindings for Delphi.

In the past we had QT 2.x integrated as CLX in Delphi.

I really hate the CLX wrappers since they were buggy and hard to extend.

But why isn't anyone making an API list of external DLL calls to use (the same way JCL wraps the Windows API).

Is it so hard to code such API function mapping? Or maybe the QT classes cannot be exposed to non-C callers?

Any hint in this direction is welcome.

Comment: I found that the Lazarus project have a QT 4.6.x binding at http://users.telenet.be/Jan.Van.hijfte/qtforfpc/fpcqt4.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've heard, apparently the cross-platform component library for Delphi XE2 (version due out next year) will be QT based, sorta like CLX only it should actually work right.

Comment: I can't wait another 2-5 years for EMB to do something as simple as bindings.

Answer (score 1):

qtintf.dll seems to be the flat API DLL you're looking for and [Qt.pas](http://freeclx.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/freeclx/freeclx/clx/Qt.pas?revision=1.4&view=markup) the corresponding import unit.

Comment: These files are not based on QT 4, but on QT 2, as far as I can guess. So they look deprecated to me, and will render awfully on screen (there is a gap in drawing between QT2 and QT4).

Comment: You're probably right, as the files are Kylix offspring. BTW: (upper case) QT = QuickTime. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you wait for VCL+, that is the Qt binding coming with the next version of Delphi.

The problem is that Qt is heavily macro-based and C++ based. So the Qt "flat API" is quite verbose and big. I wonder how EMB will create its own VCL+ binding, but I'll definitively wait for their implementation for using Qt on any Delphi project.

If you can't wait, and really want cross-platform User Interface (with Mac O$ support), I recommend using http://www.twinforms.com/products/wxformsdelphi and not Qt. It relies on a separate DLL, but it's easier to develop, and well maintained/documented.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to port the qt4.pas from 
http://users.telenet.be/Jan.Van.hijfte/qtforfpc/fpcqt4.html.

It is originally written for Lazarus but I managed to port it to Delphi.

One must do the following

1. declare

   type
     PUInt = ^Integer;
     PTRUINT = PUInt;
     PtrInt = ^Integer;
     PPtrInt = ^PtrInt;
2. comment out all calls with "qword" paramters since quad-words are not supported in Delphi
3. comment out "{$mode objfpc}{$H+}" since this is Lazarus stuff
4. replace all "cdecl; external" with "cdecl; overload; external"

Than the demos can be compiled and run just fine with Delphi.